# Read last 30,000 lines of a file

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

If has a csv file whose data will increase by time to time. Now what i need to do is to read the last 30,000 lines.

Code :

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Filename).Where(r => r.ToString() != "").ToArray();

 int count = lines.Count();

 int loopCount = count > 30000 ? count - 30000 : 0;

  for (int i = loopCount; i < lines.Count(); i++)
  {
      string[] columns = lines[i].Split(',');
      orderList.Add(columns[2]);
  }
```

It is working fine but the problem is

```
File.ReadAllLines(Filename)
```

Read a complete file which causes performance lack. I want something like it only reads the last 30,000 lines which iteration through the complete file.

PS : i am using .Net 3.5 . Files.ReadLines() not exists in .Net 3.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619735/how-to-read-last-n-lines-of-log-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398378/get-last-10-lines-of-very-large-text-file-10gb-c-sharp/398512#398512

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use `File.ReadLines()` Method instead of using `File.ReadAllLines()`

From MSDN:[File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The **ReadLines** and **ReadAllLines** methods differ as follows:
>   When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array.
>
> Therefore, when you are **working with very large files**,
>   **ReadLines** can be more efficient.

**Solution 1** :

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName).Where(r => r.ToString() != "").ToArray();

        int count = lines.Count();
        List<String> orderList = new List<String>();
        int loopCount = count > 30000 ? 30000 : 0;

        for (int i = count-1; i > loopCount; i--)
        {
            string[] columns = lines[i].Split(',');
            orderList.Add(columns[2]);
        }
```

**Solution 2:** if you are using .NET Framework 3.5 as you said in comments below , you can not use `File.ReadLines()` method as it is avaialble since `.NET 4.0` .

You can use StreamReader as below:

```
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        List<String> orderList = new List<String>();
        String line;
        int count=0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("c:\\Bethlehem-Deployment.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                count++;
            }
        }

        int loopCount = (count > 30000) ? 30000 : 0;

        for (int i = count-1; i > loopCount; i--)
        {
            string[] columns = lines[i].Split(',');
            orderList.Add(columns[0]);
        }
```

Comment: m using .net 3.5. sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui: i think `ReadLines()` is only avaialble from .NET 4.0,  you can use `StreamReader`

Comment: @ShujaatSiddiqui: check my edited answer with `solution2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `File.ReadLines` by you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned.

After that you can use the `linq` to make things lot more easier. `Reverse` will reverse the order of collection and `Take` will take the `n` number of items. Now put again `Reverse` to get the last `n` lines in original format.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(Filename).Reverse().Take(30000).Reverse();
```

If you are using the .NET 3.5 or earlier you can create your own method which works same as `File.ReadLines` like this. Here is the code for the method originally written by [@Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017918/choice-of-implementation-to-read-lines-of-file-c-sharp)

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string file)
{
   using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
   {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         yield return line;
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can use `linq` over this function as well like the above statement.

```
var lines = ReadLines(Filename).Reverse().Take(30000).Reverse();
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` reads all lines, what if the file is large ?

Comment: m using .net 3.5. sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not know where to start reading the file to get the last 30,000 lines. Unless you want to maintain a separate index of line offsets you can either read the file from the start counting lines only retaining the last 30,000 lines or you can start from the end counting lines backwards. The last approach can be efficient if the file is very large and you only want a few lines. However, 30,000 does not seem like "a few lines" so here is an approach that reads the file from the start and uses a queue to keep the last 30,000 lines:

```
var filename = @" ... ";
var linesToRead = 30000;
var queue = new Queue<String>();
using (var streamReader = File.OpenText(fileName)) {
  while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) {
    queue.Enqueue(streamReader.ReadLine());
    if (queue.Count > linesToRead)
      queue.Dequeue();
  }
}
```

Now you can access the lines that are stored in `queue`. This class implements `IEnumerable<String>` allowing you to use `foreach` to iterate the lines. However, if you want random access you will have to use the `ToArray` method to convert the queue into an array which adds some overhead to the computation.

This solution is efficient in terms memory because at most 30,000 lines has to be kept in memory and the garbage collector can free any extra lines when required. Using `File.ReadAllLines` will pull all the lines into memory at once possibly increasing the memory required by the process.

Answer (score 0):

Or I have a diffrent ideo for this.

Try splitting the csv to categories like A-D , E-G .... 
and acces what first character you need .

Or you can split data with count of entites. Every file will contain 15.000 entites for example. And a text file which will contain tiny data about entits and location Like :

Txt File:

```
entitesID | inWhich.Csv
....
```